# Skip specific documents when querying them from Firestore database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In my application user gets to pick specific documents out of the list, for example: `1,5,8` from the list containing documents `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. When logged into the application next time, I want to first fetch all of the chosen documents (considering pagination, because the number of documents user picked could be very high), and then start fetching the remaining documents as the user finishes viewing picked documents by scrolling down the list.
As it turns out, available Firestore querying methods are not capable of skipping the specific documents.

My current idea:

1. Make single document references for the user-specific documents and fetch them.
2. Make single document references for the documents between the range of user-specific documents (From the example that would be documents number: 2,3,4,6,7).
3. After that start making 'big queries' for the remaining documents.

This looks like a working solution, but I'm sure that there is a better way to accomplish the goal, since what I've done is not asynchronous and very slow. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have any way to exclude specific documents from queries.  You may only include them using some existing field values.  If you already know the documents to fetch, you can just get() them individually.

It sounds like you are already able to work around these requirements.  I don't believe you have any alternatives.

Comment: Ok. I removed the awaits and instead of adding the documents to the displayList with the add method, I assign their value to pre-known position. Although it would be very nice to have it as a Firestore function. Maybe you try to convince someone)

Comment: You are always free to file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support